# malformed url exception no protocol when loading uri strings from arrayList

Tags: java, json

It works when I hard code one URI but when I try to loop through array I get malformed URL exception.

I know there is a protocol attached. I tried adding in and taking out "" at different spots in the code. I ran it with one URI to make sure it functions correctly. I did print lines to see what the URIs were to make sure they were coming out correctly.

```
/**
 * Convert a URI into a JSON string
 * 
 * @param URI the URI of resource
 * @return String String format of JSON object in an array
 * @throws URISyntaxException 
 * @throws Exception
 */
private static String readUrl(ArrayList<String> urlStrings) throws Exception, IOException, URISyntaxException {
    String inputLine = "";
    String finalInput = "";
    int i;
     for(i = 0;i<urlStrings.size();) {
           System.out.println(urlStrings.size());
           System.out.println(urlStrings.get(i));
        if (urlStrings.get(i).contains("WADL") || urlStrings.get(i).contains("wadl") || urlStrings.get(i).contains("WSDL") || urlStrings.get(i).contains("wsdl")) {

            return null;
        }

        // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    public void checkClientTrusted(
                            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }

                    public void checkServerTrusted(
                            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error" + e);
        }


        BufferedReader in = null;
        String uri = urlStrings.get(i);
        URL url = new URL(uri);
        try {

            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

            connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(5000);

            connection.connect();

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));



            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                 //create one JSON object of all endpoints
                finalInput += inputLine;
            }
            System.out.println("Successfully processed: " + uri);
            System.out.println(finalInput);
            i++;
            return finalInput + "\n";
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot read: " + uri);
            return null;
        }
        finally {
            if (in != null)
                in.close();
        }
}
     i++;
         //return JSON object to service catalog
        return finalInput;

}
```

Hoping I can loop through array, call all endpoints, and build a JSON object to return to front end.

Comment: What is the URL string that is causing the exception?

Comment: https://fasoa-prd1.corp.wpsic.com/IDCardRequest/swagger/docs/v1
You will not be able to access it
It doesnt matter what the url is. When I hard code it in it works, when I loop through array I get an error.

Comment: I have to wonder if there are unprintable characters in the strings which are making them invalid.  Try printing out `urlStrings.get(i).matches(".*[\\p{C}\\p{Z}].*")`.

Comment: Thats what is was! I had to escape the quotes around the uri being passed in from the array!